# PostgreSQL 9.3 - creation of Group Role causes permission problems

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created the following **Group Role**:

```
CREATE ROLE hr_user
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
```

Then I gave some of my **Login Roles** the new group role permissions:

```
GRANT hr_user TO "iris";
GRANT hr_user TO "jeff";
```

Now, I have a query that checks shows all workers if user has "hr_users" if not it shows only users in specific status:

```
select *
from users
where case when (select pg_has_role(select "current_user"(), 'hr_user'::name, 'MEMBER'::text)) then 1=1 else userstatus <>'Active' end
```

Basicly this query means that:

If user has hr_user then do:

```
select *
from users
where 1=1
```

If user doesn't have hr_user then do:

```
 select *
 from users
 where userstatus <>'Active'
```

This works fine from my PgAdmin Console.

However when users try to access from their desktop software a weird error appears:

> Error: role "iris" does not exists

If I remove my new code the error is gone.

My question:
Why the creation of the new group role causes PostgreSQL to believe that the user role does not exists? What can i do?

Comment: It is really weird. Do you use same schemas you and your colleagues? Is the role granted on all schemas?

Comment: @MiloBellano roles are server wide, not per schema and not even per database.

Comment: thanks :D quite new with postgres.

Comment: Can you try using this version of your SQL? `select * from users where pg_has_role('hr_user'::name, 'MEMBER'::text) or userstatus <>'Active'`

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Thank you! that solved the problem... But i'm not sure why it happened in the first place... Both statements should be the same for the current session isn't it?

Comment: Yes, they should. I have no clue why it would say that role does not exists for whatever is returned by `current_user`. What I can say is that your query would not work for me __as is__ in my GUI, because you can't pass select as parameter. You would have to enclose it in parenthesis. But I doubt it would explain error you are getting.

Comment: As a follow-up to @ŁukaszKamiński comment, it looks like the query has been manually edited in the question at exactly the place where the problem is, masking it with another problem. In its current form, the question can hardly be answered or researched.